# Codeigniter: My controller is not able to access the model

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller

**//My controller section**

```
<?php
class Myadmin extends CI_Controller 
{
            public function _construct()    
            {
             parent::_construct();
             $this->load->library('form_validation');
             $this->load->helper('form');
             $this->load->model('adder','',TRUE);
            }

            public function index() 
            {
                    echo " i am about to call the model";
                    $this->adder->insert_user();        
            }
}
?>    
**//My model section**

<?php
class Adder extends CI_Model    {
        function_construct()    {
            parent::_construct();
        }

        public function insert_user()   
        {
              echo " Hi ,the model is accessed";    
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: These aren't actually in the same file, are they?

Answer (score 2):

Is it because of "function_construct()"?
It has no space and you should use two _

function _*construct(){
     parent::*_construct();
} 
Same in Controller

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you load the model in your controller.

In the current version of the CodeIgniter you should do something like this:

```
//loading the model
$this->load->model('adder', 'fubar');

//accessing it's functions
$this->fubar->function();
```

for more info see [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading).

**EDIT:**
You have defined a `_construct()` function which must be __construct().
Also you should fix `parent::_construct();` to `parent::__construct()`.

Comment: also your code has a problem in it's constructor as WordsWorth mentioned.